# Rails render json - how to download response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How can I set up reponse so that dynamically generated json data will be downloaded by browser, not displayed?

I'm using Active Admin

```
  member_action :download, :method => :get do
    application = Application.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: application.to_json( include: { categories: { include: { my_cases: { include: [{ questions: { include: :answers } }, :keys ] } } } } ) }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `send_data` method:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { send_data application.to_json( include: { categories: { include: { my_cases: { include: [{ questions: { include: :answers } }, :keys ] } } } } ), type: :json, disposition: "attachment" }
end
```